# Oracle sqlplus nested select's not working

Tags: oracle, select, sqlplus

I am trying to display the supplier code, supplier name and postcode of all suppliers who satisfy every stock item they supply
having a price value above the average of all stock items.

I have been trying for a while, and this is the best I can come up with, although it isn't working

```
SELECT SuppName, SuppCode, Postcode
FROM Suppliers 
WHERE Suppliers.SuppCode = (
SELECT SuppCode
FROM Stocks 
WHERE Suppliers.SuppCode = Stocks.SuppCode
GROUP BY SuppCode
HAVING MIN(Price) > AVG(Price)
);
```

If anyone could give me a hint in the right direction as to where I am going wrong it would really be appreciated.

```
   create table Stocks
  (StockNo      number(6) not null primary key,
   StoreCode    varchar2(6) not null, 
   Description  varchar2(24),
   Quantity     number(6),
   Units        varchar2(12),
   Reorder      number(6),
   foreign key (StoreCode)
     references Stores(StoreCode));

   create table Suppliers
  (SuppCode  varchar2(4) not null primary key,
   SuppName  varchar2(30),
   Street    varchar2(24),
   Town      varchar2(16),
   County    varchar2(16),
   PostCode  varchar2(10),
   TelNo     varchar2(16),
   FaxNo     varchar2(16))
  cluster SupplyData(SuppCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the codes for these supplies, I would go for aggregation.  You seem to want:

```
SELECT s.SuppCode
FROM Stocks s
GROUP BY s.SuppCode
HAVING MIN(s.Price) > (SELECT AVG(s2.Price) FROM Stocks s2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had this at one point but was then struggling with obtaining the supplier name and postcode aswell because I can't group when using two tables. I Tried using it as a sub query but it returns multiple rows so I was a bit stumped and ended up trying other solutions. Sorry i'm still on a learning curve with oracle, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @cmorga1 . . . You can get the supplier name by using an explicit `JOIN` or `IN` operator.